# AWK - match multiple patterns and print results

Tags: shell, awk

Using my limited scripting knowledge.. I have put together an expect script to run some commands on specific devices. The output is below and is saved from all devices to a file (I just listed 2 devices as an example).

l

```
lssystem | grep -i physical
physical_capacity 82.85TB
physical_free_capacity 20.50TB
IBM_FlashSystem:SU73VAWFS15:config>
lssystem | grep -i physical
physical_capacity 82.85TB
physical_free_capacity 21.12TB
IBM_FlashSystem:SU73VAWFS16:config>
```

What I would like is to get some values from the output and have them displayed in rows, delimited by "," :

```
SU73VAWFS15,82.85TB,20.50TB
SU73VAWFS16,82.85TB,21.12TB
```

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to do this, here's a kludgy util based method, (assuming the input has no surprises):

```
lssystem | grep -i physical |
tr ': ' '\t' | cut -f 2 | xargs | { read a b c ; echo "$c,$a,$b" ; }
```

...or even:

```
lssystem | grep -i physical |
xargs | { IFS=' :' read a b c d e f g ; echo "$f,$b,$d" ; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the request is to convert the combined output into a single CSV file, given that the commands where executed using 'expect', and can not be executed directly. The following is a small script to reformat combined output.

```
awk -v OFS="," '
$1 == "lssystem" {
    key = cap = free = ""
} 
$1 == "physical_capacity" { cap = $2 }
$1 == "physical_free_capacity" { free = $2 }
$1 ~ /config>$/ {
    split($1, a, ":" ) ;
    key = a[2] ;
    print key, cap, free
    key = cap = free = ""
}
' < input-file
```

Small suggestion: when collecting data over multiple systems, better to create some form of blocks that will make it easier to parse the data with various tools, for example:

```
=== BEGIN name-of-host
lssystem | grep -i physical
physical_capacity 82.85TB
physical_free_capacity 20.50TB
IBM_FlashSystem:SU73VAWFS15:config>
=== END
```